# Pytorch - RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train a small model. But I always encounter the same error that is

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

My forward function for the model:

```
def forward(self, data, steps):
        v_pred = []
        B = data.shape[1]
        for i in range(steps-1):
            v_obs = self.layer(data[i]-data[i+1])
            v_pred.append(v_obs.view(1, B, -1))
        v_pred = torch.cat(v_pred, 0)
        
        return v_pred
```

This is my train scripts

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    v_pred = model(data, steps)
    loss = loss_fn(v_pred, v_act)

    optim.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

Thanks in advance